# How to record canvas streaming?

Tags: html, ionic2, html5-canvas, video-streaming

I am working with HTML5 video and canvas.My requirement is to record live video stream with video editing.

For this I use navigator.getUserMedia method to capture the live streaming.

What I did is - I have a video tag in which live streaming is coming.
I have canvas in my html, I use two canvas one over another- first canvas shows video streaming and canvas2 is used for editing on live stream.

Here is the code - that get video and shows on canvas

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: {facingMode: {exact: "environment"}}}, (stream) => {

      this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      this.video = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#video');
      this.videostream = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#videostream');

      this.myStream = stream;
      this.video.srcObject = this.myStream;

      this.canvas2 = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas2');
      this.canvas3 = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas3');

      let self = this;
      this.video.addEventListener('play', () => {
        function step() {
          self.ctx.drawImage(self.video, 0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);

          requestAnimationFrame(step)
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(step);
      })

    }, (error) => {

    });
```

As I need to do editing also I create a new canvas3 - combination of canvas one and canvas two.And show the canvas3 stream on new video tag

Here is the code of drawing -

```
handleMove(event) {
    var canvasPosition = this.canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();

    let currentX = event.touches[0].pageX - canvasPosition.x;
    let currentY = event.touches[0].pageY - canvasPosition.y;

    let ctx = this.canvas2.getContext('2d');

    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.stroke();
    this.lastX = currentX;
    this.lastY = currentY;


    /*for canvas recording*/
    var ctx3 = this.canvas3.getContext('2d');
    ctx3.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0);
    ctx3.drawImage(this.canvas2, 0, 0);

    let canvasStream = this.canvas3.captureStream(60);

     this.videostream.srcObject = canvasStream;

     this.videostream.play()
     this.videostream.addEventListener('play', () => {
     })

  }
```

Here is my html code-

```
 <video id="video" controls="false" style="width: 100%; height: 30%;" autoplay playsinline></video>

  <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 30%;position: absolute"></canvas>

  <canvas id="canvas2" style="background-color: transparent;width: 100%; height: 30%;position: relative"
          (touchstart)="handleStart($event)" (touchmove)="handleMove($event)"></canvas>

  <canvas id="canvas3" style="width: 100%; height: 30%;"></canvas>

  <video id="videostream" controls="false" style="width: 100%; height: 30%;" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

My problem is I am not able to show the canvas stream as video.

I also did some digging on google and find some plugins/library for recording like -  RecordRtc,CanvasCamera etc but I didn't get help from it.

Expected output - show canvas stream as a video.

Current output -  I get a single streams of canvas and its shows like image in "videostream" in video tag.

Is anyone know how to do it?

Any help will be appreciated